# Identificar y seleccionar casos duplicados

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo necesito identificar cuantos casos duplicados tengo en una columna y crear otra columna que me ayude a identificarlos. Por ejemplo, mi columna original es `col_1` y `col_2` identifica los casos que están duplicados, definiendo con "0" los casos únicos y con un "1" los duplicados.

```
Col_1 | Col2
|A    |  1
|B    |  0
|C    |  1
|C    |  1
|C    |  1
|D    |  0
|E    |  0
|A    |  1
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Con R base

Lo primero es contar las ocurrencias en `Col1`, luego unimos este conteo con los datos originales y cada valor de `Col1` tendra su correspondiente conteo, luego simplemente habrá que determinar si este es mayor a 1 para indicar si el valor se repite o es único:

```
# Agrupamos por Col_1 y obtenemos el tamaño de cada grupo
recuento <- aggregate(. ~ Col_1, df, length)
# Unimos los dos data.frames
new_df <- merge(df, recuento)
# Calculamos la nueva columna
new_df$Col2 <- ifelse(new_df$Col2> 1, 1, 0)
new_df
```

#### Mediante `tidyverse`

Es la misma idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Col_1) %>% 
  mutate(Col2 = if_else(n()>1, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, filtré la base y cree una nueva que agrupa todos los casos duplicados, pero necesito mantener solo los casos únicos. Cómo puedo hacerlo? usé este código para hacer el filtro:
`duplicados <- filter(base, dupl_idest >= 1)`

Y para eliminar los duplicados he usado este código: 
`base <- duplicados %>% group_by(dupl_idest) %>% 
                                          slice_max(, with_ties = FALSE)`
Pero solo me funciona si defino como criterio de mantención de los casos la fecha más reciente y no quiero tener un criterio para eso

Comment: Si quieres los casos únicos, no te sirve hacer `filter(base, dupl_idest < 1)` ?

Comment: No, porque me quedo sin casos, todas las observaciones están duplicadas.

Comment: Entonces, creo que no entendí lo que comentas, ¿por qué no haces una nueva pregunta en el sitio?